# Bluetooth connect return an error 10051

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi, bluetooth

We are creating application to communicate external device with windows PC (here we are using windows 7)

I planned to create socket programming by using win32.but connecting with bluetooth device have problem, below code we are using.

```
        //
        // Connect the socket (pSocket) to a given remote socket represented by address (pServerAddr)
        //
                    //sizeof(SOCKADDR_STORAGE)) == SOCKET_ERROR
        if ( SOCKET_ERROR == connect(LocalSocket,
                                     (struct sockaddr *) &SockAddrBthServer,
                                     sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH)) ) {
            wprintf(L"=CRITICAL= | connect() call failed. WSAGetLastError=[%d]\n", WSAGetLastError());
            ulRetCode = CXN_ERROR;
            break;
        }
```

while connecting the socket its shows 10051 error, And i changed to the Port to

```
SockAddrBthLocal.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
SockAddrBthLocal.port = BT_PORT_ANY;
```

it shows the Error `10049`

i googled it but cant find the problem.

i checked with the inputs but everthing was fine, local socket also created successfully. Below image shows the inputs.

[image]

I took the btaddress and serviceClassid in the bluetooth device info properties.

[image]

Please help what was wrong in this.

Comment: [Windows socket error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx) 10051 is *"**WSAENETUNREACH**: Network is unreachable. A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. This usually means the local software knows no route to reach the remote host."* My guess is, that you are passing the wrong service class ID or *btAddr* for the [SOCKADDR_BTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363057.aspx). But it's hard to tell with the little information available (I don't know, where you took the last 2 screenshots, for example).

Comment: @IInspectable : I took the screenshots from "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers" in that bluetooth device right click properties-> hardware-> properties->details.. please tell me what information you need. thanks

Comment: Did you read the MSDN documentation yet? [Bluetooth Programming with Windows Sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362928.aspx).

Comment: Yes, I took the sample from same site, https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Bluetooth-Connection-e3263296

Comment: any special drivers need to install?